# private static const in business layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, class-library

I'm writing a Web api for a mobile application, which replies back with httpResponseMessages. I've run into a problem which i'm too novice to fix.

Basically, in my business layer class library I have a private reference to a file:

```
 private const string FiFile = @"C:\DirectoryFile\FI.dat";
```

this const is being called by another part of my solution (Web pages), and is never used/or called when using the mobile calls.

However, if i deploy the mobile api, without this directory on the server it throws an exception.

I basically have 4 projects in one solution, one for web, one for mobile, and both have a reference to the business layer.

Please can you advise how I can prevent this from happening?

The only way i've been able to stop it, is to phsyically created the above folder/file.

** Update **
the error is as follows:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The type initializer for BusinessLayer.BIFacade' threw an exception."

ExceptionMessage":"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\DirectoryFile\\FI.dat'.
```

*** UPDATE ***
When i debug, and use fiddler to make my api calls, the visual studio stops here:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, BiData> SBicDirectory =
        File.ReadAllLines(FiFile).ToDictionary(line => line.Substring(3, 11), line => CreateBiData(line));
```

which is where it is trying to use the FiFile const, which is in the constructor.

*** EDIT ***
Doohhhh - its late. it's in the constructor, so guess what :-)

Comment: And the exception is? Don't let us hanged with this suspense....

Comment: You should look at the code where the exception happens. Having a string that looks like a file name doesn't mean that it has to be a file name or that anything automatically checks if the file exists. There has to be some code that specifically uses the string as a file name and tries to access the file.

Comment: sorry, yeah that may help.

Comment: @Guffa, there is a method in my businesss layer, that does indeed use the constant, however, the mobile application doesnt call this method.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee It must, unless it's a static constructor. Use a debugger to place a breakpoint to confirm, then look at the stack trace in the exception to see which method ultimately originated the call.

Comment: In the update, that would be a static initializer. Gets called when anything in the class gets used. Your easy fix is to make it `Lazy<T>` and it will only get it's real initialization the first time it's used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a muppet - it's in the constructor therefore, will always be called. Sorry everyone.

Comment: No problem -- 99% of my coding frustrations are pretty simple to fix and thus overlooked. Next time you can right click the variable or method that is causing the exception and choose for "find all references". This will show all lines of code that are accessing the value.